# What is the intellij equivalent of Emacs' M-\ (delete-horizontal-space)?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-13, intellij-15

In Emacs the `M-\` keybinding (alt and backslash) runs the e-lisp function 'delete-horizontal-space'.

When `M-\` is pressed in any of the whitespace between two words on a line it deletes all whitespace between those two words e.g. `"word1 word2"`, `"word1     word2"` would both become `"word1word2"`.

When `M-\` is pressed in any of the whitespace between the start of a line and the first character on the line it deletes all whitespace. So:
`"        word1"` becomes `"word1"`.

When `M-\` is pressed in any of the trailing whitespace of a line it deletes it.

My question is: ***does intellij have a keybinding for the same functionality? If not, how can I make `M-\` behave as in intelliJ as it does on Emacs?***

Comment: 1. No. 2. Write your own plug-in with this action.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - thanks - if you add this as an answer I will accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have a built-in action for that, one can implement it as a plug-in. You can check the open source [IdeaVim](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim) plug-in which provides a lot of custom editor actions.